# How does the linker know where to look for a function implementation in C++?

Tags: compilers, c, c++

I am currently learning about how the compilation and linking works in C++. I think I kinda get how the compiler works, and that for a file to fully compile you don't need to have function implementations, but only declarations. It is the linker's job to link the function declaration to its implementation.

But now I have this weird question, for example if I have a `.cpp` file in which I am using 1000 different functions, and each of those functions has its own separate `.cpp` and `.h` file, how does the linker know which of the cpp files to scan to find that specific function? I mean does the linker know where the function is located or does the linker every time for every function scan the whole project to find that specific function?

Comment: Good explanations here. Another thing to know is that the compiler doesn't know anything about the .h files. Header files are just for the convenience of us developers. The preprocessor takes the .h files and literally includes them into the .cpp files that ask for them (as in, it replaces the #include statements with the actual text of the included file) - and *that's* what's fed into the compiler. (You can try this manually on a small program: it can all be just .cpp files - but you'll see that it gets tricky and tedious rather quickly as your program grows).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compiler compiles from a .cpp file to an object file (.o) with the binary code.

The linker combines all of the object files together into a single binary.

So, the linker doesn't need to know which cpp to look at, because the linker doesn't look at cpp files.  Instead, the linker looks at all of the .o files, figures out where all the functions are, and combines them together.

Comment: So does that mean that if I have for example 10 .o files (which are all used in the main) then when the linker links everything, the end result of a .exe file is a combination of all those 10 .o files?

Comment: @artas2357 Yes, in general. Although there can be optimizations -- if none of the external functions or variables in a `.o` file are referenced, it can be omitted from the executable.

Comment: can you recommend a good detailed book which explain this in more details ? I am just interested in all operation going on inside, Thanks

Comment: The linker would also need to make sure there are no constructors of objects of static lifetime that would need to be run before it can safely omit the `.o` file.  (Whereas if you've put some objects into a static library, then typically you've implicitly accepted that some `.o` files from that library might not get linked in, even if they do have such constructors in them.)

Comment: @Raziel "Linkers and Loaders" by John Levine is easily the best book on this subject. There are completely legal free copies on the Internet which you can ask your favourite search engine about.

Comment: In fact, it may be the only book on this subject.

Comment: I have one additional question which might be out of scope for this main question, but I have heard this term "translation unit" when talking about compilers, what does this term mean?

Comment: @artas2357: "Translation" is just an older / alternative term for "compilation". So, a "translation unit" is a "compilation unit", i.e. the unit the compiler works on. Depending on the programming language, the development environment, and the compiler, the translation unit may be a file, component, package, module, class, method, or whatever the author wants. In many cases, you can think of "translation unit" as equal to "source file", but remember that there are environments (for example typical Smalltalk systems such as Squeak and Pharo) which don't even *have* a concept of "file".

Comment: So can I name the .obj or .o files as a "compilation unit"?

Comment: @Pseudonym Any chance you can provide a link?  The author's webpage appears to used to have links to a pre-edited version, however the links have been taken down.  Other sources appearing in google are sketchy "free ebook" websites of which at least the top link had the .pdf taken down due to a DCMA claim.

Comment: @Chuu Oh, the author's web page was the version I knew about.

Answer (score 13):

The linker is given explicitly the list of files to use, in the command line of the linker. They can be object files (.obj / .o) - compiled code - or libraries (.lib / .a) - object files structured in a single one.

Part of the job of the linker is to establish a list of the available functions and assign them an address in memory. This is enough to generate the calls where needed.

Note that the linker does not see the source code itself.

Comment: I am wondering how the "calls where needed" are made, I mean how does a linker know that if a main uses a function add() that it has look or scan all the .o files until it finds an implementation of add(), or does it already know where to look for that add() function?
Sorry if the question sounds weird, I really want to understand this concept of compiling + linking.

Comment: @artas2357: Part of the job of the linker is to establish a list of the available functions and assign them an address in memory.

Comment: @artas2357 The structure of the object file includes a list of all the names it references that aren't defined in that object file. The linker looks for these in the other object files.

Comment: @artas2357 Although a compiler and a linker are completely at liberty to organize it as they want, for all practical purposes, any half decent compiler will put some kind of a table into the object file that links the various symbols of the program (including but not limited to functions) to their implementation and to other pieces of information that's needed for the linker. So, a linker will very probably not scan anything but use this lookup table to find what it needs.

Comment: @Gábor: this is the case for a library file. For objects, I am not sure.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Then grab any object file and a corresponding object file dumper like `objdump` or `dumpbin` and you'll see it, actually.

Comment: @Gábor: tell the OP, not me.

Comment: 1. The linker is typically not given the _full_ list of files explicitly, but rather `-lfoo`, and it goes looking for `libfoo.a` (or `foo.lib` etc.) in various places. 2. The linker may or may not see the source, or something like the source, depending on whether link-time optimization is enabled.

Comment: @einpoklum: 1. this remark adds nothing. The list is indeed given explicitly, modulo filename construction and path resolution. These are side details.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: So, not explicitly. You could say it is semi-explicit, but - if it's not perfectly explicit, you haven't answered the question in the title.

Comment: @einpoklum: the question is about where to find the functions, not the files. Don't harass.

Answer (score 8):

> It is the linker's job to link the function declaration to its implementation

This is not true. This is the compiler's job. Essentially the declaration (I'm assuming you mean the prototype, as in `return_type function_name (arguments...)`) is part of the language to allow you to tell the compiler what the function looks like before the compiler finds its implementation (the code body between `{` and `}`).

A lot of functions in fact are declared at the same place they are implemented. However it is also common to declare function prototypes without an implementation in headers or in virtual classes. This basically tells the compiler "hey, this is what the function looks like, but you will find the implementation later or somewhere else".

By the time you run the linker it is no longer processing things like declarations. Instead, linkers deal only with compiled code and some of that code consists of functions.

The final binary code does not actually contain any function definitions. Instead, code is simply a long list of machine instructions. A function is simply an address to somewhere in the code. For example a function like `add()` may be located at the 12566th byte of the binary code (or 0x00003116 in hex which is a more common way to look at addresses). The code that calls that function will simply be the instruction `call 0x00003116`. At this stage there is no information that that location contains a function.

However linkers work with object (or library) files that contain metadata, not just pure binary code. The actual format of these files depend on a lot of things - the language you use, the operating system you are on, the type of file etc. (for example, obj files in C/C++, lib files on Linux, dll files on Windows, etc.). However, what these files must contain is a list of what is sometimes called "symbols" and what addresses those symbols point to. These symbols are basically the function signature which tells the linker things like what the function's name is in the source code, how many arguments the function accepts, etc. This list of symbols is usually called the symbol table.

Actually, during compilation the compiler keeps a data structure called the symbol table in RAM in order to remember what it has compiled. Once the code is compiled, the compiler will format this symbol table appropriately and insert it in the object or library file.

When the linker sees that some code is calling `add()` it scans the list of files it is working on (or it looks up the database/array that it stored all the scanned files) and checks their symbol table to find `add()`. Once found, it will replace the caller's symbol with the address of the `add()` function (eg, 0x00003116). There is another step called the fixup which recalculates the address in RAM depending on how the executable or library file is loaded into RAM but I'll leave the details of that process as further research. It's enough to know that the linker's job is to load all the files you pass to it, remember all their symbol tables, and then replace symbols in code with actual addresses in memory.

Answer (score 3):

For C and C++, the linker's job is the same, ignoring template classes/functions.

The .o / .obj files are split into Sections, each of which has a Symbol Table.

The Symbol Table has the offset into this Section of each exported Symbol (function, global variable), and a set of relations. These are the function calls, and references to global variables. The linker will determine which Object file contains _main, and add it to the .exe it is building. It will then scan the relocations for the Section, and determine that _add is being used. It then finds the .obj file that provides _add, and adds it to the .exe. It then patches the Section that has _main at the offset given in the Relocation Table, and writes the Absolute or Relative address of _add here. It then locates all the Symbols that the Section that _add requires, and processes them in the same way.

A .a / .lib file is a collection of Object files, optionally with an Index that lists all the Symbols the Library contains, for MS Visual Studio, this Index file is processed once, and the object files are added to the .exe as needed.
UNIX traditionally only scans Library files when needed, and if a Library needs another Library, then this must be listed before the requiring Library.

A worked example may be helpful.
Assuming that the linker is looking for _main, and it finds it in foo.obj, at offset 100 in the .DATA Section.
This Section is added to the .DATA Section of the .exe, and the caller is updated to have the address of _main. A C or C++ program does not start at _main - there is a function the initialises the C run time, any global variables, and then calls _main. In MSVC command-line programs this is _mainCRTStartup, but will have other names for other compilers.

The linker then finds _add in bar.c in Section .DATA, and adds it to the .DATA section.
Assume that foo.c .DATA Section  was 500 bytes longs, this means that bar.c .DATA section is now at 500 bytes in. _add is 200 bytes into bar.obj .DATA setion, so _add is 700 bytes into the .exe .DATA section. Thus 700 is written into the .exe .DATA section at location 100 - which is where _add is called. The process repeats until all Relocations have had their Sections added to the .exec.